# Скрипт выводит записи из бд в другой кодировке

Tags: php, mysql

Скрипт чата выводит записи из бд в другой кодировке.

Вводит в нужной cp1251, а выводит каракули. В htaccess всё прописано. Сам скрипт:

```
<?php

define("HOST", "localhost");
define("USER", "user");
define("PASSWORD", "Pass");
define("DB", "db");

/************************
FUNCTIONS
/************************/
function connect($db, $user, $password){
$link = @mysql_connect($db, $user, $password);
@mysql_query('set character_set_client="cp1251"'); // Это устанивки кодировки ввода, работают
@mysql_query('set character_set_results="cp1251"');
@mysql_query('set collation_connection="cp1251_general_ci"');

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1251'"); // Пробую это на вывод, в итоге каракули
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'cp1251'");

if (!$link)
    die("Could not connect: ".mysql_error());
else{
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB);
    if(!$db)
        die("Could not select database: ".mysql_error());
    else return $link;
}
}

// Здесь получение данных из базы

function getContent($link, $num){
$res = @mysql_query("SELECT date, user, message FROM shoutbox ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ".$num, $link);

if(!$res)
    { die("Error: ".mysql_error()); }
else
    { 
return $res; }
}

// Здесь вставка сообщения, работает норм.

function insertMessage($user, $message){
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO shoutbox(user, message) VALUES('%s', '%s');",         mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($user)),     mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($message)));
$res = @mysql_query($query);
if(!$res)
    die("Error: ".mysql_error());
else
    return $res;
}

/******************************
MANAGE REQUESTS
/******************************/
if(!$_POST['action']){

header ("Location: index.php"); 
}
else{
$link = connect(HOST, USER, PASSWORD);
switch($_POST['action']){
    case "update":
        $res = getContent($link, 10);
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
            $result .= "<p><strong>".$row['user']."</strong><img src=\"css/images/bullet.gif\" alt=\"-\" />".$row['message']." <span class=\"date\">".$row['date']."</span></p>";
        }
        echo $result;
        break;
    case "insert":
        echo insertMessage($_POST['nick'], $_POST['message']);
        break;
}
mysql_close($link);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В случае, если кодировка сайта и базы данных не совпадает (часть текста на сайте выводится нормально, а часть текста из базы - в виде непонятных знаков). Необходимо в скрипте, который подключается к базе данных добавить команды, которые укажут MySQL серверу кодировку, в которой выводить текст. В зависимости от того, какую библиотеку PHP вы используете команды будут выглядеть так:

**Для библиотеки mysql**

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

**Для библиотеки mysqli**

```
mysqli_query($link, "SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_general_ci'");
mysqli_query($link, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
```

где:

- вместо utf8 необходимо указать нужную
     кодировку (например cp1251)
- вместо `utf8_general_ci` нужное сопоставление кодировок (например
     `cp1251_general_ci`). Полный перечень
     кодировок и сопоставлений MySQL
     доступен в документации.
- для библиотеки mysqli первым параметром указывается указатель на
     подключение к БД - в вашем скрипте он
     может быть отличным от $link, узнать
     его можно посмотрев в исходном коде
     название переменной, которой
     присваивается результат выполнения
     функции mysqli_connect().

Для библиотеки PDO при инициализации нового подключения нужно добавить 4й параметр:

```
$db = new PDO(DB_DSN, DB_USER, DB_PASS, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));
```